# Time complexity of recursive method involving a tree traversal

Tags: performance, recursion, time

I'm trying to get my head around the calculation of time complexity of my own method - can anybody nudge me in the direction of calculating a method involving a for each method which involves a recursive call on itself?

I've written a method that does a tree traversal of an -nary tree. Unfortunately I can't post the exact code, but it goes: given the root node to start with

```
for each (child of node)
   does a quick check
   sets a boolean
   does a recursive call on itself until we go to the lead nodes
```

Comment: you do that for each child node so this loop runs for each child node of each child node.. you're visiting `n` nodes ..

Comment: "recursive call on itself" - is there any other kind?  That's the definition of recursion.

Comment: the part I'm confused is, (analysing the operations line by line), is the for each part done n times, or the part where I do the recursive call?

Comment: @user3603183 It seems you're having troubles understanding what recursion is doing. I'll try to explain it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your loop visits every node of the tree exactly *once*.

Beginning withe the root node, you visit all of its child nodes which for them you call the same function on every child node of the root-child nodes and the same repeats.

Since you visit every node exactly once this loop has a runtime of `O(n)` for `n` nodes of your tree assuming that `quick check` is constant and does not depend on `n` or does anything that exceeds `O(n)`.

---

"*is the for each part done n times*":

Yes and no: The `for each` part is done `numberOfChildsOfNode(Node node)` for a single node but since you do that *for each child node* by calling your function recursively the number of times this is executed is actually `n` times.

**What you can test/try:** Declare a `static` variable `executionCount` or somtheing like that, initialize it to `0` and increment it inside your loop. You should see that `executionCount` equals the number of nodes.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! I understood on the whole that it's done n times, as I had to write a line by line analysis of the work done by the method I got a bit confused. In the end I ended up lumping the for each and recursive call together to give n times